# How to not display a specific children[ ] from PageView?

Tags: flutter

I have a PageView with some page

```
 PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);



      PageView(
      controller: _pageController,

      children: [

     //  ----------------------page 1------------------------
      
       Stack(
         children: [

            new Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
              child :
              Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
               new RaisedButton(
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
             elevation: 5,
             highlightElevation: 10,
              color: Colors.white,
              splashColor: Colors.white,
              child :  new  Text("Non",textAlign: TextAlign.center,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize:  SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 5)),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all (15.0),
              onPressed: () {
             Choix=false;
                }),

           new RaisedButton(
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
           elevation: 5,
            highlightElevation: 10,
            color: Colors.white,
            splashColor: Colors.white,
            child :  new  Text("Oui",textAlign: TextAlign.center,  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize:  SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal! * 5)),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all (15.0),
            onPressed: () {
            Choix=true;
             }),
             ],
              ),
             ),
             ]
          ), 


     //  ----------------------page 2------------------------

Container(), // if button==true I want remove page 2


     //  ----------------------page 3------------------------

Container(),// if button==true I want remove page 3


     //  ----------------------page 4------------------------

Container(),// page 4

 ]
 )
```

At the page1, if the user pressed a button, I search to display only

```
PageView
[page1 
page4]
```

I try to use visibility but page 2 et page 3 are just white, and not jumped or remove

```
PageView
[page1

 visibility(
   child: page2)  //return white

     visibility(
   child: page3) // return white
    page4]
```

I can make a logic to jump page like

```
 if (button==true && page_controlleur==2){
 jump_page=4
 }


 if (button==true && page_controlleur==3){
 jump_page=1
 }
```

But it's ugly, during the transition it reveal the page I don't wont to show

Comment: Can you include minimal widget that you are working on?

Comment: I have edit my post with more detail